# Bundler doesn't permit using gems in project home directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm working on a program that assists in running Ruby code on the command line (at https://github.com/keithrbennett/rexe, `gem install rexe`).

When I `gem install` it, and cd to the project root, and try to `require` a file not in the Gemfile, it fails:

```
➜  rexe git:(master) ✗   rexe -r awesome_print -oa '"hello"'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    12: from /Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    11: from /Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    10: from /Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/rexe:23:in `<main>'
     9: from /Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/rexe:23:in `load'
     8: from /Users/kbennett/work/rexe/exe/rexe:403:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler.rb:313:in `with_clean_env'
     6: from /Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler.rb:562:in `with_env'
     5: from /Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler.rb:313:in `block in with_clean_env'
     4: from /Users/kbennett/work/rexe/exe/rexe:403:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/kbennett/work/rexe/exe/rexe:385:in `call'
     2: from /Users/kbennett/work/rexe/exe/rexe:385:in `each'
     1: from /Users/kbennett/work/rexe/exe/rexe:385:in `block in call'
/Users/kbennett/work/rexe/exe/rexe:385:in `require': cannot load such file -- awesome_print (LoadError)
```

However, when I `cd ~`, it works fine:

```
➜  ~   rexe -r awesome_print -oa '"hello"'
"hello"%
```

I wrapped my code in `Bundler.with_clean_env`, which I thought should take care of this.

I can use the Ruby interpreter directly and it works:

```
➜  rexe git:(master) ✗   ruby -r awesome_print -e "ap 'hello'"
"hello"
```

So I guess Bundler is making an assumption that non-Gemfile-listed gems should not be permitted to be loaded, and that is almost always reasonable, but in my case, where the program should be able to load any gem whatsoever, it is an impediment.

I understand that Bundler is finding the Gemfile[.lock] and doing what it thinks is right, but is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, just a direction: try adding the path to the requested gem to `$LOAD_PATH` explicitly before requiring the gem. For example:

```
pry(main)> require "awesome_print"                                                                    
LoadError: cannot load such file -- awesome_print
```

But then

```
pry(main)> $LOAD_PATH << "<home>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/awesome_print-1.8.0/lib/";
pry(main)> require "awesome_print"
=> true
```

Voila! The question is how to get the proper path for the gem, maybe `gem which` could help...

Comment: Thank you! I have implemented this at https://github.com/keithrbennett/rexe/blob/070766f6925cb097442d9f57f168f04f66c4e753/exe/rexe?#L379-L394. I hope there would be a better long term solution (a Bundler option maybe), but at least this works around the problem.